# async/await is behaving weirdly by restarting already executed code

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I am seeing some weird behavior related to async/await, but I can't explain it.

Here is the basic logic:

```
public async Task Init(UI.INavigable NavigateFrom) <-- Starts from here
{
    await NavigateFrom.Navigate<UI.Pages.Page>(await Common.CreateDrillInNavigationTransitionInfo(), async (Page) =>
    {
        // ...
        m_SelectPage.OnCategorySelected += OnCategorySelected;
        // ... (including more awaits)
        await OnModelUpdated();
        return Page;
    });
}

private async Task OnModelUpdated()
{
    await m_SelectPage.DataUpdated(...);
}

public async Task DataUpdated(...)
{
    try
    {
        m_Initializing = true;
        await Common.RunUiTask(async () =>
        {
            // ... (including more awaits)
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                // ... (including more awaits)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("DataUpdated: Calling CategorySelected\n");
                await OnCategorySelected(await GetSelectedCategory());
            });
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        m_Initializing = false;
    }
}
private async Task OnCategorySelected(Model.Category Category)
{
    Debug.Print("OnCategorySelected start\n");
    var Adaptor = new Model.Adaptor(...);
    var p = new InfoPage(m_ActualApp, Adaptor);
    Debug.Print("OnCategorySelected navigate\n");
    await p.Init(SelectPage);
    Debug.Print("OnCategorySelected end\n");
}

public async Task Init(UI.INavigable NavigateFrom)
{
    Debug.Print("Init start\n");
    await NavigateFrom.Navigate<UI.Pages.InfoPage>(await Common.CreateDrillInNavigationTransitionInfo(), async (Page) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("Init lambda\n");
        // ...
        Debug.Print("Init lambda update\n");
        await m_InfoPage.Updated(...);
        Debug.Print("Init lambda end\n");
        return Page;
    });
    Debug.Print("Init end\n");
}
```

And here is the output from one run (it doesn't behave the same way every time):

```
DataUpdated: Calling CategorySelected
OnCategorySelected start
OnCategorySelected navigate
Init start
OnCategorySelected start
OnCategorySelected navigate
Init start
Init lambda
Init lambda update
OnCategorySelected start
OnCategorySelected navigate
Init start
Init lambda end
Init end
OnCategorySelected end
Init lambda
Init lambda update
Init lambda
Init lambda update
Init lambda end
Init end
OnCategorySelected end
Init lambda end
Init end
OnCategorySelected end
```

As is clearly seen from the output, it seems that as soon as it hits await in the Init function, or it hits await inside the lambda in the Init function, it suspends (which is correct), but then restarts back in the OnCategorySelected function for no apparent reason.

I can't explain what's happening. It should just happen once since there is no code that calls OnCategorySelected again. Any ideas?

For reference, here are the utility functions that I use in case there's some weirdness in those:

```
public static async Task<DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo> CreateDrillInNavigationTransitionInfo()
{
    return await Common.RunUiTask(async () =>
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
    });
}
    
public static class Common
{
    public static async Task<T> RunUiTask<T>(Func<Task<T>> F)
    {
        return await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunTaskAsync(async () =>
        {
            return await F();
        });
    }       
}

public static class DispatcherTaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> RunTaskAsync<T>(this CoreDispatcher Dispatcher, CoreDispatcherPriority Priority, Func<Task<T>> Func)
    {
        var TaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Priority, async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var R = await Func();
                TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(R);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TaskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
            }
        });
        return await TaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public static async Task<T> RunTaskAsync<T>(this CoreDispatcher Dispatcher, Func<Task<T>> Func)
    {
        return await RunTaskAsync(Dispatcher, CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Func);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant even see the code that calls `OnCategorySelected` once... or who raises the event, or what its connected to. Im guessing this is out of your control

Comment: Well, it's always a tradeoff between a lot of code and a minimal example. I didn't think the code calling the function was necessary since the root of the problem seems to stem from there, but I updated my original post with some more code calling the OnCategorySelected function. I also added prints to every possible call to the function and it turns out there is only one.

Comment: Subscribe an event only **once**.

Comment: And also consider to unsubscribe from the event too.

Comment: Thank you. I think that did the trick. I really had to control the life time of the logic classes and properly unsubscribe from the events. I was confused by the debugger behavior.